# My program that searches the given value in the memory doesn't work

Tags: c++, c, windows

The first program is used to give a value to the second, which in turn searches the first's memory for that value. In this case, the first gave the value 12345, so the second should search for 12345.

**The first program:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int a = 12345;
  printf("%d\n", a);

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;

}
```

**The second program:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>

DWORD dwAdapteRecord[1024];          //used to entry the record that is eligibility             
int iPosition=0;                     //used to indicate the  position in the array dwAdapteRecord
 int count=0;

HANDLE CreateTheTestProcess()                           //create the process of the first programme used as a test 
{
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(&si) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = TRUE;

wchar_t szCommandLine[] = L"C:\\Users\\Adminstrator\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\Debug\\ConsoleApplication1.exe";
CreateProcess(NULL, szCommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

return pi.hProcess;



}


void ComparePage(HANDLE hProcess,DWORD dwValue,DWORD dwBaseAddress)                  //compare the memory in one page to the given value
{
byte bOnePage[4 * 1024];
if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwBaseAddress, bOnePage, 4 * 1024, NULL));

DWORD *pdw;

count++;
printf("%d\n", count);


pdw = (DWORD*)bOnePage;
for (int i=0; i < 1024;i++)
{

    if (iPosition >= 1024)
    {
        printf("the array is out of its size\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (dwValue == *pdw)                              //if the 4 Byte value in the memory is equal to the given value ,
    {                                                      //then entry the address of it
        dwAdapteRecord[iPosition] = dwBaseAddress+i;
        iPosition++;
    }


}
}


void Find(HANDLE hProcess,DWORD dwValue)                                     //compare the 2GB memory that the first programme have,in this function
                                                                         //will call the ComparePage function{
DWORD dwBaseAddress = 64 * 1024;
DWORD dwOnePage = 4 * 1024;
DWORD dwOneGb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

for (int i = 0; i < ((2 * dwOneGb) / dwOnePage); i++)
    ComparePage(hProcess, dwValue, dwBaseAddress + i*dwOnePage);
printf("The search is finish\n");
}


void ShowList()                       //show the result
{
printf("The result is：\n");
for (int i = 0; i < ::iPosition; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", ::dwAdapteRecord[i]);
}
printf("The value of the variable iPosition is:\n", ::iPosition);
};


int main()
{
printf("%d\n", iPosition);
system("PAUSE");
HANDLE hProcess = CreateTheTestProcess();
Find(hProcess, 12345);
ShowList();

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

But the result is that the second program can not find a 4 byte block of data that is equal to the given value (12345). The `ShowList()` function shows that the record is zero. Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: You only ever look at the first 4 bytes of each page, repeatedly. In `ComparePage`, `pdw` is assigned once and remains unchanged. Also, check that `ReadProcessMemory` actually succeeds.